# Nonempty intersection of cosets of finite-index subgroups

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, abelian-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\lcm{lcm}$This question is crossposted from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4800809/nonempty-intersection-of-finite-index-subgroups).

Let $H_1,\dots,H_{n+2}$ be cosets of finite-index subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ and suppose for all $i=1,\dots,n+2$, $\bigcap_{j\neq i}H_j$ is nonempty. Is it then true that $\bigcap_{j=1}^{n+2}H_j$ is nonempty?

Some comments:

- The statement is true for $n=1$. My proof required using that for any $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}^{>0}$ we have $\gcd(a,\lcm(b,c))=\lcm(\gcd(a,b),\gcd(a,c))$). This is a one-dimensional analogue of what I say I tried below.
- The following statement is false: Let $H_1,\dots,H_{n+1}$ be cosets of finite-index subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ and suppose for all $i=1,\dots,n+1$, $\bigcap_{j\neq i}H_j$ is nonempty. Then $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n+2}H_i$ is nonempty. Counterexample: For $i=1,\dots,n$ let $H_i=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}^n;x_i\text{ is even}\}$ and let $H_{n+1}=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}^n;\sum_jx_j\text{ is odd}\}$.
- Something I tried: we can suppose WLOG that $0\in H_1\cap\dots\cap H_{n+1}$, so that $H_1,\dots,H_{n+1}$ are subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, and $H_{n+2}=p+V$, for some $p\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ and some finite-index subgroup $V$ of $\mathbb{Z}^n$. Then we know that, for all $i=1,\dots,n+1$, the fact that $\bigcap_{j\neq i}H_j$ is nonempty means that

$$p\in V+\bigcap_{j\in\{1,\dots,n+1\}\setminus\{i\}}H_j.$$
That is, for all $i=1,\dots,n+1$, $p$ can be expressed as $v_i+x_i$, where $v_i\in V$ and $x_i\in\bigcap_{j\in\{1,\dots,n+1\}\setminus\{i\}}H_j$.

It would be enough to prove that this implies
$$p\in V+\bigcap_{j=1,\dots,n+1}H_j,$$
which is equivalent to $\bigcap_{j=1}^{n+2}H_j$ being nonempty.

Comment: You better change that title.

Comment: @FZaldivar, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457901/nonempty-intersection-of-finite-index-subgroups#comment1186110_457901), I changed it.

Comment: Whoops sorry. I also changed the one in MSE, which I copied without thinking

Comment: Cross-posted (something you should not do): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4800809/nonempty-intersection-of-cosets-of-finite-index-subgroups

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that the intersection of (finitely many) full-rank lattices is also a fumm-rank lattice, as it also has finitely many cosets. So all intersections under consideration, if nonempty, are full-rank.

Now, we may assume that $0\in\bigcap_{j\neq n+2} H_j$. For $i=1,\dots,n$, choose $p_i\in\bigcap_{j\neq i}H_j$ so that $p_1,\dots,p_n$ are independent (as all intersections are full-rank, this is possible). Finally, choose $p\in\bigcap_{j\neq n+1}H_j$.

There is an expansion
$$
  p=\frac1d\sum_{i=1}^na_ip_i,
$$
where $d,a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb Z$, and $\gcd(a_1,\dots,a_n)=1$. Then there exist $k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n k_ia_i=1$.

Now we claim that all the $H_j$ contain the element
$$
  q=\sum_{i=1}^n k_ia_ip_i. \tag{$*$}
$$
Indeed, since $p_1,\dots,p_n\in H_{n+1}\cap H_{n+2}$, and the sum of their coefficients in $(*)$ is $1$, we have $q\in H_{n+1}\cap H_{n+2}$ (in fact, we do not need $0\in H_{n+1}$). On the other hand, if $i\leq n$, then
$$
  q-k_idp=\sum_{j\neq i}(k_ja_j-k_ia_j)p_j\in H_i,
$$
so $q\in H_i$ as well.

**REmark.** We used the condition that the $H_i$ are full-rank, but it seems that this condition is superfluous. Indeed, if we had a counderexample $H_1,\dots,H_{n+2}$ where, say, $H_{n+2}$ is not full rank, we could add to $H_{n+2}$ a full-rank lattice so that there still would be no common intersection. For that purpose, let $L$ be the lattice whose coset is $H=\bigcap _{j\neq n+2}H_i$, and let $a\in H_{n+2}$, $b\in H$. Then we can take a lattice $L+\langle 2(a-b)\rangle$ and complete it to the full-rank lattice.